# Производительность web-страницы и Electron/NW.js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, node.js, производительность, electron

Как я понимаю Electron/NW.js по сути просто открывает окно браузера с нужным контентом, но если взять web-страницу и открыть её в Chrome и ту же саму страницу запихнуть её в Electron/NW.js будет ли отличатся производительность?
Под производительностью я понимаю как CSS анимации, так и скорость выполнения JS. (Время загрузки страницы не особо интересует)
Примеры задач:

- (CSS) При наведении на картинку она увеличивается - проседания по FPS
- (JS+CSS) При клики на ссылку отменяется стандартное действие и страница прокручивается - как время от клика и до начала прокрутки, так и FPS при прокрутки
- (JS) Парсинг JSON строки - время обработки строки

Буду рад как и домыслам так и обоснованным ответам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теории, производительность Electron и NW.js должны быть сравнимыми с соответствующими десктопными версиями Chrome/Chromium. Я тесты не делал, но не заметил особых отличий в русурсоёмких частях приложения, над которым работал.

В NW.js версий до 0.22 была проблема с значительным падением производительности, если использовалась компиляция в V8 Snapshot, которая позволяет защитить код приложения от декомпиляции. Начиная с версии 0.22 эту проблему исправили.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю в плане производительности Electron быстрее (буквально на несколько миллисекунд приложение запускается и отвечает на запросы извне быстрее).

Сравнение движков в плане разработки:

## Защита исходного кода

В Electron нет какого-либо механизма для защиты вашего исходного кода. Asar трудно назвать приемлемой защитой, учитывая что это простой tar-архив и фактически любой пользователь может «распаковать» вашу программу как обычный архив и получить доступ ко всем ресурсам и исходному коду.

NW.js позволяет собрать исполняемый файл с защитой через V8 Snapshot. Данное решение конечно не компилирует JavaScript в машинный код (как утверждает документация) и не обеспечивает полную безопасность исходного кода. По сути это просто очень хорошо обфусцированный код. Но если единственная альтернатива — оставить исходный код совершенно открытым, то многие разработчики предпочтут V8 Snapshot, даже учитывая потерю примерно 30% производительности.
**Победитель**: NW.js

## Время запуска

Я не пытался специально замерять время запуска приложения, но по личным ощущениям приложение на Electron запускается заметно быстрее как на Windows, так и на OSX. Даже если отключить V8 Snapshot, NW.js-приложение загружается гораздо медленнее.
**Победитель**: Electron

## Open Source

В свое время Electron сделал смелый шаг, поддержав IO.js в момент застоя разработки Node.js. Это означает, что Electron в большой степени стремится поддерживать передовые возможности JavaScript, в то время как NW.js больше ориентируется на поддержку обратной совместимости (по крайней мере в теории).

Также нельзя не заметить высокую скорость разработки Electron. Больше сотни коммитов в неделю, по десять релизов в месяц. Команда разработчиков активно отвечает на вопросы на github. С другой стороны, NW.js все еще находится в версии 0.15, а github-документация кажется довольно устаревшей. Например, регулярно можно увидеть упоминания названия «node-webkit», хотя проект был переименован несколько лет назад.
**Победитель**: Electron

## Послужной список

Несмотря на то, что NW.js существует дольше Electron'а, насколько я могу судить, на Electron разработано гораздо больше популярных приложений. Из данного списка NW.js, кроме Popcorn Time и Koala, трудно выделить что-либо значительное. С другой стороны список Electron смотрится гораздо солиднее:
— Atom
— Slack
— Visual Studio Code
— Cocos Creator
— Pixate Pixate
**Победитель:** Electron

Так что я смело бы выбирал Electron.

Comment: Вы сравниваете NW.js и Electron, а в вопросе было сравнение их с обычным браузером.